# get data from javascript object without using key name

Tags: javascript, jquery

currently working with jquery object

the object contains data like

```
data[0]={CustUserID: 31, FirstName: "System12", LastName: "Administrator", CustUserName: "SysAdmin"}
```

this object contains n number of records,and we get the length using `data.length`

and also each object each record contains different type of keys and n number of keys with value

so now i am trying to get each key name and value name from each record and need to show on page.

on html view:

```
CustUserID=31
FirstName=System12
LastName=Administrator
CustUserName=SysAdmin
```

the code i wrote for this is

```
  var data="";
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
    {
    data= data+"</br>CustUserID="+data[i].CustUserID+
               "</br>FirstName="+data[i].FirstName+
               "</br>LastName="+data[i].LastName+
               "</br>CustUserName="+data[i].CustUserName;

    }

$("#DivData").html(data);
```

but i stucked when data keys are dynamically changing according to user requirment so at that i am facing problem to get data, so i need to get key names and data should be looped dynamically.

please help me...

thank you guys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery `.each()`

```
var data_result = '';
//first loop will go trough all data array elements
$.each(data, function(key, data_element){
    // second loop will go trough all object keys
    $.each(data_element, function(key, value){
        data_result += '<br/>' + key + '= ' + value);
    });
});
$("#DivData").html(data_result );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without jQuery too

```js
     var data = {
       CustUserID: 31,
       FirstName: "System12",
       LastName: "Administrator",
       CustUserName: "SysAdmin"
     };
     var dataHtml = '';

     for (var p in data) {
       if (data.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
         dataHtml += '<br/>' + p + "=" + data[p];
       }
     }

     $("#DivData").html(dataHtml);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="DivData"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var mydata = Array(), result;
    mydata[0]={CustUserID: 31, FirstName: "System12", LastName: "Administrator", CustUserName: "SysAdmin"};
    for (var key in mydata[0]){
        var obj = mydata[0][key];
        result += '<br/>'+key+'='+obj;
    }
```

jQuery("#myid").html(result);